# repmgr on PostgreSQL 10 failed, recovering

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, repmgr

I'm running a 3 nodes PostgreSQL 10 + repmgr 4.4 cluster:

- **1 master node** (postgres1.domain.local)
- **2 stabdby nodes** (postgres2.domain.local and postgres2.domain.local)

The cluster was running fine before a complete restart. After the reboot the standby nodes are not connected to the master:

```
postgres@postgres1:/$ repmgr -f /etc/repmgr.conf cluster show
 ID | Name                    | Role    | Status        | Upstream                | Location | Priority | Timeline | Connection string                                                     
----+-------------------------+---------+---------------+-------------------------+----------+----------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1  | "postgres1.domain.local" | primary | * running     |                         | default  | 100      | 6        | host=postgres1.domain.local user=repmgr dbname=repmgr connect_timeout=2
 2  | "postgres2.domain.local" | standby | - failed      | "postgres1.domain.local" | default  | 100      | ?        | host=postgres2.domain.local user=repmgr dbname=repmgr connect_timeout=2
 3  | "postgres3.domain.local" | standby | ? unreachable | "postgres1.domain.local" | default  | 100      | ?        | host=postgres3.domain.local user=repmgr dbname=repmgr connect_timeout=2

WARNING: following issues were detected
  - unable to connect to node ""postgres2.domain.local"" (ID: 2)
  - unable to connect to node ""postgres3.domain.local"" (ID: 3)
  - node ""postgres3.domain.local"" (ID: 3) is registered as an active standby but is unreachable
```

This is the status of repmgr on **postgres2** and **postgres3**:

```
postgres@postgres2:/$ repmgr -f /etc/repmgr.conf cluster show
ERROR: connection to database failed
DETAIL: 
FATAL:  the database system is starting up
FATAL:  the database system is starting up

DETAIL: attempted to connect using:
  user=repmgr connect_timeout=2 dbname=repmgr host=postgres2.domain.local fallback_application_name=repmgr

postgres@postgres3:/$ repmgr -f /etc/repmgr.conf cluster show
ERROR: connection to database failed
DETAIL: 
FATAL:  the database system is starting up
FATAL:  the database system is starting up

DETAIL: attempted to connect using:
  user=repmgr connect_timeout=2 dbname=repmgr host=postgres3.domain.local fallback_application_name=repmgr
```

PostgreSQL is starting on **postgres2** and **postgres3**, and it is hanged on recovering:

```
postgres@postgres2:/$ ps ax|grep postgres
  430 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf
  431 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: 10/main: startup process   recovering 0000000600000000000000DF

postgres@postgres3:/$ ps ax|grep postgres
  430 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf
  431 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: 10/main: startup process   recovering 0000000600000000000000DF
```

In the PostgreSQL log file on both **postgres2** and **postgres2** I see the following lines:

```
postgres@postgres2:/$ tail /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log
2019-10-08 18:15:31.033 CEST [431] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/DFD5A5E0: wanted 24, got 0
2019-10-08 18:15:36.038 CEST [431] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/DFD5A5E0: wanted 24, got 0
2019-10-08 18:15:41.043 CEST [431] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/DFD5A5E0: wanted 24, got 0
2019-10-08 18:15:46.048 CEST [431] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/DFD5A5E0: wanted 24, got 0
2019-10-08 18:15:51.054 CEST [431] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/DFD5A5E0: wanted 24, got 0
2019-10-08 18:15:56.059 CEST [431] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/DFD5A5E0: wanted 24, got 0
2019-10-08 18:16:01.064 CEST [431] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/DFD5A5E0: wanted 24, got 0
2019-10-08 18:16:06.069 CEST [431] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/DFD5A5E0: wanted 24, got 0
2019-10-08 18:16:11.075 CEST [431] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/DFD5A5E0: wanted 24, got 0
2019-10-08 18:16:16.080 CEST [431] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/DFD5A5E0: wanted 24, got 0

postgres@postgres3:/$ tail /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log
2019-10-08 18:16:08.171 CEST [431] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/DFD98148: wanted 24, got 0
2019-10-08 18:16:13.176 CEST [431] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/DFD98148: wanted 24, got 0
2019-10-08 18:16:18.181 CEST [431] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/DFD98148: wanted 24, got 0
2019-10-08 18:16:23.187 CEST [431] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/DFD98148: wanted 24, got 0
2019-10-08 18:16:28.192 CEST [431] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/DFD98148: wanted 24, got 0
2019-10-08 18:16:33.197 CEST [431] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/DFD98148: wanted 24, got 0
2019-10-08 18:16:38.202 CEST [431] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/DFD98148: wanted 24, got 0
2019-10-08 18:16:43.207 CEST [431] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/DFD98148: wanted 24, got 0
2019-10-08 18:16:48.213 CEST [431] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/DFD98148: wanted 24, got 0
2019-10-08 18:16:53.218 CEST [431] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/DFD98148: wanted 24, got 0
```

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Those lines from the log you posted:

```
2019-10-08 18:16:43.207 CEST [431] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/DFD98148: wanted 24, got 0
```

are low level notice that usually occur whilst trying to read an incomplete WAL file on a standby server, or during crash recovery on a primary.

Unless these are followed by a higher level error you can safely ignore them.

If the replication doesn't work after the restart probably there were some changes that were activated by the restart. 
Control your pg_hba or postgresql.conf ( also postgresql.auto.conf) and see if all the settings are correct.

However, the postgresql.log either on the master or on the standbys should give you some information on what the problem is.